# Getting VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT with MoltenVk/Vulkan on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, clang++, vulkan

I'm trying to setup vulkan/MoltenVk on Mac and I am having some trouble getting Validation Layers and Extensions working.

I have downloaded/installed both MoltenVk and the vulkan libraries, setup some environment variables:

```
export VULKAN_SDK=/opt/vulkan-sdk
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
export VK_ICD_FILENAMES=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/vulkan/icd.d/MoltenVK_icd.json
export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
export VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation
```

**vulkaninfo works as expected and shows 6 validation layers.**

When I try to build my own project it can't find the layers.

I created a small test project to try and figure out what's going on. It compiles and links without errors, but when I run it I get

```
[***MoltenVK ERROR***] VK_ERROR_LAYER_NOT_PRESENT: Vulkan layer VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation is not supported.
vkCreateInstance result: -6
```

main.cpp (copied from https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/latest/mac/getting_started.html)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    VkInstance instance;
    VkResult result;
    VkInstanceCreateInfo info = {};
    uint32_t instance_layer_count;

    result = vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&instance_layer_count, nullptr);
    std::cout << instance_layer_count << " layers found!\n";
    if (instance_layer_count > 0) {
        std::unique_ptr<VkLayerProperties[]> instance_layers(new VkLayerProperties[instance_layer_count]);
        result = vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&instance_layer_count, instance_layers.get());
        for (int i = 0; i < instance_layer_count; ++i) {
            std::cout << instance_layers[i].layerName << "\n";
        }
    }

    const char * names[] = {
        "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation"
    };
    info.enabledLayerCount = 1;
    info.ppEnabledLayerNames = names;

    result = vkCreateInstance(&info, NULL, &instance);
    std::cout << "vkCreateInstance result: " << result  << "\n";

    vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

build

```
clang++ main.cpp 
-I/opt/vulkan-sdk/include/ 
-rpath /opt/vulkan-sdk/lib 
-L/opt/vulkan-sdk/lib/ 
-lMoltenVk 
-lvulkan 
-lVkLayer_core_validation 
-lVkLayer_object_lifetimes 
-lVkLayer_stateless_validation 
-lVkLayer_thread_safety -lVkLayer_unique_objects 
-o output
```

Note that I'm linking against the .dylibs, but I tried previously with the .framework libraries as well.

I suspect that I need to link something else, or add a particular environment variable or #define in code.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are linking your application incorrectly.

The MoltenVK library (dylib) is considered as an ICD (Installable Client Driver) by the Vulkan loader.  The loader is the library you are linking with `-lvulkan` in your link command.  The Vulkan loader dynamically loads ICDs at execution time.  When using the Vulkan loader, ICDs are not linked directly to the application.

Similarly, the Vulkan loader dynamically loads the layers at execution time.  Layers are not linked directly to the application.

The MoltenVK library is a little unusual because it is built in such a way that an application can link to it directly and run MoltenVK (Vulkan subset) applications without using the loader and layers.

But if you want to use the loader and layers, you don't link MoltenVK and the layers to your application.  You link only the loader.  The loader then dynamically loads the MoltenVK lib as an ICD and dynamically loads the layers if requested.

In your case, it looks like you are linking the MoltenVK library first.  This may end up satisfying all the Vulkan symbols first via the MoltenVK library.  The Vulkan loader in your library list is probably not even being included in your executable because of MoltenVK being there and the Vulkan loader isn't actually doing anything.

I think if you remove `-lMoltenVK` and the 5 other layer libs, you'll do better.

You can also set `VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all` in your environment to see what the loader is doing.  I suspect that if you run your current app with this set, you won't see anything because the loader isn't getting involved.

See https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.1.101.0/mac/loader_and_layer_interface.html  for more info.

Comment: Thanks Karl. That was exactly it. 
`clang++ main.cpp -I/opt/vulkan-sdk/include/ -rpath /opt/vulkan-sdk/lib -L/opt/vulkan-sdk/lib/ -lvulkan -o output` 
Was enough to get it working.